# How to scrape data from the website which is not aligned properly

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    html_content = """<p class='3D"MsoNormal"'><b><span ;verdana&quot;,sans-serif"="" style='3D"font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"='>Address</span></b><span style='3D"font-size:11.0p=' t;font-family:&quot;verdana&quot;,sans-serif"="">
</span><span style='3D"font-size:11.0pt"'><u></u><u></u></span></p>
<table border='3D"0"' cellpadding='3D"0"' cellspacing='3D"0"' style='=3D"width:98.0%"' width='3D"98%"'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td 9.9="5pt" 9.95pt="" 9.95pt;border-radius:3px"="" style='3D"background:whitesmoke;padding:9.95pt' valign='3D"top"'>
<div id='3D"m_-5523088575981856726m_693960596679990068tdf_8"'>
<p class='3D"MsoNormal"'><span neue&quot=';;color:black"' style='3D"font-family:"Helvetica'><a href='3D"https://maps.google.com/?q=3D406+Pine+Run%2C+Knig=' htdale%2c+nc+27545"="" target='3D"_blank"'>406 Pine Run, Knightdale, NC 27545
</a></span><span style='3D"font-size:11.0pt"'><u></u><u></u></span></p>
</div>
</td>
<td .75pt="" .75pt"='id=3D"m_-5523088575981856726m_693960596679990068tdl_9"' colspan='3D"2"' style='3D"padding:.75pt' valign='3D"top"'>
<p class='3D"MsoNormal"'><b><span ;verdana&quot;,sans-serif"="" style='3D"font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"='>Dispatch Region</span></b><span style='3D"font-si=' ze:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;verdana&quot;,sans-serif"="">
</span><span style='3D"font-size:11.0pt"'><u></u><u></u></span></p>
<table border='3D"0"' cellpadding='3D"0"' cellspacing='3D"0"' style='=3D"width:98.0%"' width='3D"98%"'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td 9.9="5pt" 9.95pt="" 9.95pt;border-radius:3px"="" style='3D"background:whitesmoke;padding:9.95pt' valign='3D"top"'>
<div id='3D"m_-5523088575981856726m_693960596679990068tdf_9"'>
<p class='3D"MsoNormal"'><span neue&quot=';;color:black"' style='3D"font-family:"Helvetica'>7</span><span style='3D"font-size:11.0pt"'><u></u><u></u></span></p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<td .75pt="" .75pt"="" 88575981856726m_693960596679990068tdl_10"="" id='3D"m_-55230=' style='3D"padding:.75pt' valign='3D"top"'>
<p class='3D"MsoNormal"'><b><span ;verdana&quot;,sans-serif"="" style='3D"font-size:11.0pt;font-family:"='>Market:</span></b><span style='3D"font-size:11.0p=' t;font-family:&quot;verdana&quot;,sans-serif"="">
</span><span style='3D"font-size:11.0pt"'><u></u><u></u></span></p>
<table border='3D"0"' cellpadding='3D"0"' cellspacing='3D"0"' style='=3D"width:98.0%"' width='3D"98%"'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td 9.9="5pt" 9.95pt="" 9.95pt;border-radius:3px"="" style='3D"background:whitesmoke;padding:9.95pt' valign='3D"top"'>
<div id='3D"m_-5523088575981856726m_693960596679990068tdf_10"'>
<p class='3D"MsoNormal"'><span neue&quot=';;color:black"' style='3D"font-family:"Helvetica'>Triangle</span><span style='3D"font-size:11.0pt"'><u></u><u><!--=
u--></u></span></p>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Is it possible to scrape the data based on image attached from html content

[image: Html source]

Output:

```
Address : 406 Pine Run, Knightdale, NC 27545
Dispatch Region : 7
Market: Triangle
```

How to find the structure to get the details of the labels?

Comment: Please provide a correct HTML example, assume the address tag is also in an `<td>` and so on.

Comment: `for p in soup.select("p"):     print(p.text.strip())` This seems to give a good enough result so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK I still don't quite get the question...but if you start from the innermost table and no extra `p` tags, as the title is bold with `b`, and input isn't, try:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
p = soup.find_all('p')
result = {}
for i in range(len(p)-1):
    if p[i].find('b') and not p[i+1].find('b'):  #assuming there is a 'p' even for empty input
        result[p[i].text.strip()] = p[i+1].text.strip()
        i += 1
print(result)
```

output

```
{'Address': '406 Pine Run, Knightdale, NC 27545', 'Dispatch Region': '7', 'Market:': 'Triangle'}
```