# How to extract the details from particular HTML text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
html_content = """<div id="formContents" class="dformDisplay ">
<div class="sectionDiv expanded">
<table id="sect_s1" class="formSection LabelsAbove">
<tr class="formRow ">
<td id="tdl_8" class="label lc" >
<label class="fieldLabel " ><b >Address</b></label>
 <table class="EmailFieldPadder" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top" style="width:98%;margin-top:.3em;margin-right:1.5em;">
 <tr><td class="EmailDivWrapper" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;padding: 0.83em;border-radius:3px;margin:0;border:0px;">
    <div id="tdf_8" class="cell cc" >
    <a
href="https://maps.google.com/?q=1183+Pelham+Wood+Dr%2C+Rock+Hill%2C+SC+29732">1183
Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732</a>
</span></div>               
</td></tr></table>
</td>
"""
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    form_data = soup.find("div",{"id":"formContents"})
    if form_data:
        section_data = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"sectionDiv expanded"})
        for datas in section_data:
            labels = datas.findAll("label",{"class":"fieldLabel"})
            for item in labels:
                labels = item.text
                print(labels)
                entity_data = item.findAll("td").text
                print(entity_data)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

My required output:

```
Address : 183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732.
```

Is there any solution to get the particular output using `beautifulsoup`. I need to the address of the particular HTML source content.

Comment: Yes, beatifulsoup is made for this. What was the problem?

Comment: I am unable to get the address 183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732 from the html content. But I get the label

Answer (score 1):

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

---

You could select all `<td>` with `<label>` in your element and use `stripped_strings` to extract the contents - In case it is the same motive as in [How to scrape data from the website which is not aligned properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75407616/how-to-scrape-data-from-the-website-which-is-not-aligned-properly) you could get a nicly structured `dict` of label and text

```
dict(e.stripped_strings for e in soup.select('#formContents td:has(label)'))
```

or this if it is close to the requirements from [How to extract the data from the html content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75421490/how-to-extract-the-data-from-the-html-content):

```
dict((e.text,e.find_next('td').get_text(strip=True)) for e in soup.select('label'))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_content = """<div id="formContents" class="dformDisplay ">        
<div class="sectionDiv expanded">
<div class="Title expanded ToggleSection shead"
  style="margin-top:1em"
 id="sect_s11Header">
<div><!--The div around the table is so that the toggling can be animated smoothly-->
<table id="sect_s1" class="formSection LabelsAbove">
<tr class="formRow ">
<td id="tdl_8" class="label lc" >
<label class="fieldLabel " ><b >Address</b></label>
 <table class="EmailFieldPadder" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" valign="top" style="width:98%;margin-top:.3em;margin-right:1.5em;">
 <tr><td class="EmailDivWrapper" style="background-color:#f5f5f5;padding: 0.83em;border-radius:3px;margin:0;border:0px;">
    <div id="tdf_8" class="cell cc" >
    <a
href="https://maps.google.com/?q=1183+Pelham+Wood+Dr%2C+Rock+Hill%2C+SC+29732">1183
Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732</a>
</span></div>               
</td></tr></table>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)

dict(e.stripped_strings for e in soup.select('#formContents td:has(label)'))
```

##### Output

```
{'Address': '1183\nPelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732'}
```

Comment: There are multiple datas in html your code is not working for that case. How to make changes in labels = datas.findAll("label",{"class":"fieldLabel"}) to get td text

Comment: So there would be scope to improve your question and provide appropriate examples and details to take these circumstances into account. however, to get just this string use `soup.select_one('#formContents td:has(label)').get_text(':',strip=True).replace('\n', ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

You can search for `a` tag where `href` starts with `https://maps.google.com`:

```
>>> soup.find('a', {'href': re.compile('^https://maps.google.com')}).text.replace('\n', ' ')
'1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732'
```

The important thing here is not the `soup` object used but the strategy with a regexp to extract the address text from the tag.

Answer (score 0):

When I try your code, it prints

> ```
> Address
> ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
> ```

You should take note of the second line, because *`item.findAll("td").text`* will always raise error; you can instead do something like `'\n'.join([td.text for td in item.findAll("td")])` and that should not raise any error.

However, it will return only an empty string [as `item.findAll("td")` is an empty `ResultSet`] because with *`for item in labels....item.findAll("td")...`*, you're looking for `td` tags *inside* the `label` tags when they're actually in a `table` tag **next** to the label.

---

##### Solution 1: Using [`.find_next_siblings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling)

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
form_data = soup.find("div",{"id":"formContents"})
if form_data:
    section_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"sectionDiv expanded"})
    for datas in section_data:
        labels = datas.find_all("label",{"class":"fieldLabel"})
        for item in labels: 
            print(item.text) ## label
            for nxtTable in item.find_next_siblings('table'):
                print('\n'.join([td.text for td in nxtTable.find_all("td")]))
                break ## [ only takes the first table ]
```

<sup>[Like this, you shouldn't need the `try...except` either.]</sup>

And [for me] that printed

> ```py
> Address
>
>
> 1183
> Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732
> ```

---

##### Solution 2: Using [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

section_sel = 'div#formContents div.sectionDiv.expanded'
label_sel = 'label.fieldLabel'
for datas in soup.select(f'{section_sel}:has({label_sel}+table td)'):
    labels = datas.select(f'{label_sel}:has(+table td)')
    labels = [' '.join(l.get_text(' ').split()) for l in labels]
    entity_data = [' '.join([
        ' '.join(td.get_text(' ').split()) for td in ed.select('td')
    ]) for ed in datas.select(f'{label_sel}+table:has(td)')]
    # data_dict = dict(zip(labels, entity_data))
    for l, ed in zip(labels, entity_data): print(f'{l}: {ed}')
```

And that should print

> ```py
> Address: 1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732
> ```

Btw, *`dict(zip(labels, entity_data))`* would have returned <kbd>`{'Address': '1183 Pelham Wood Dr, Rock Hill, SC 29732'}`</kbd>, and I've used `' '.join(td.get_text(' ').split())` instead of just `td.text` (and same with `l` in `labels`) to minimize whitespace and get everything in one line.

---

**Note:** Both solutions become less reliable unless each label is for exactly one table; the second solution assumes that the table is [directly adjacent](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/combinators/#adjacent-sibling-combinator) to the label (and will skip any labels without an adjacent table with `td` tags); and the first solution risks taking a table from the next label if a label is missing a table after it.